# Как показать элемент после ввода кода с помощью jquery?

Tags: jquery, javascript, html, css

На сайте после ввода в текстовое поле условного пароля мы покажем скрытый div.
Понятно, что пароль будет в самом html'е, но это простая защита от любопытных глаз (в данном случае этого хватит).
Как это сделать, куда копать?

Comment: Если проверять по базе данные не нужно, то определитесь сначала с условием, по которому вы будете показывать этот html, например, ввод минимальной длины пароля или окончание ввода данных.

Comment: @MasterAlex, омг, по соответствию пароля, который лежит в соседнем элементе, ну написано же.

Comment: @AntonFix, самая простая реализация

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var password = $.trim($('#hidden-password-holder').text());
        $('#password').keyup(function() {
            if ($(this).val() === password) {
                $('#protected').show();
            }
        })
    });

* `#hidden-password-holder` - элемент, внутри которого записан пароль
* `#password` - поле ввода пароля
* `#protected` - скрытый див

Comment: А где хранится само условие (пароль)?

Comment: @Etki, ну да, неправильно понял условие. @AntonFix, исходя из написанного выше кода, условие хранится в html, добавьте этот кусок в любое место страницы: <span style="display:none" id="hidden-password-holder">Пароль</span>

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо большое за помощь!
Вот оформленный ответ.

В html'е вот это:

```
<span style="display:none" id="hidden-password-holder">password0101</span>
<label>Введите пароль:</label>
<input type="text" id="password" />
<div style="display:none" id="protected">Оно самое</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var password = $.trim($('#hidden-password-holder').text());
        $('#password').keyup(function() {
            if ($(this).val() === password) {
                $('#protected').show();
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @AntonFix, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.
____

@AntonFix, и не пишите стили в самом элементе, вынесите их в таблицу стилей.

Answer (score 0):

Можно перекинуть пароль в md5, взять md5.js, сравнивать хэши - и в итоге пароль не будет свободно храниться в html)).

Это дополнительный плюс в защиту - от тех, кто знает, что можно открыть html и посмотреть.

А вот от разбирающегося человека это, естественно, не защита (можно тупо взять и показать элемент), тут нужен другой путь. И он есть...

Создать файл с именем пароля, ну или хэша, и редиректить по вводу на него).

Comment: Автор указал, что это не критично, поэтому можно хранить пароль в HTML. Хозяин - барин.